# How to get wifi standard

Tags: android, standards, wifi

How can I get and change wifi standard, which I'm using now in my android device.
For example: *IEEE 802.11b or IEEE 802.11g or IEEE 802.11n.*
If this is possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its not possible to get what type of network the phone is connected to. However you can find the speed of the network:

```
    WifiManager wifiManager = Context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
    WifiInfo wifiInfo = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
    if (wifiInfo != null) {
        Integer linkSpeed = wifiInfo.getLinkSpeed(); //measured using WifiInfo.LINK_SPEED_UNITS
    }
```

P.S.: You can probably guess the type of network by interrogating the encryption on the network. But there is no built in method.

Comment: Are there any update on the issue? Its been 5 years since.

Comment: There is a new method available from API 30 and up: `WifiInfo.getWifiStandard()`