# How to know upload transfer speed 

Tags: android, performance, transfer

I want to determine transfer speed possible on a connection before uploading, for example an image. How can I do this in android? Any suggestions?

Comment: Here is a lesson from google how to determine connectivity status: http://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/connectivity-monitoring.html

Answer (score 0):

Not the speed, as far as I know,

Rather the connection type:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/ius4garTtGA

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiInfo.html

Also, please reference [How to get wifi standard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8624763/how-to-get-wifi-standard) which was just posted, should help!

Comment: Hey, I've seen you posting a few answers that basically contain only links. This isn't optimal, links can go down and are an indirect answer. Please read [this discussion](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers). Rather summarize the answer and refer with a link to further information. Thank you. :)

Comment: Cool. Thanks for the tip. I will do that from now on. But to tell you the truth I put in as much as the OP put in, relatively speaking.

Comment: I know what you mean, but always keep in mind that you also help X search engine users behind the scenes. :)

Comment: Absolutely! Thanks again for the metaread. I do agree, and will do my best from now on!